# Вывод содержимого консоли

Tags: vb.net, cmd, консоль

C помощью функции Shell я могу выполнить команду в консоле

```
commandc = "md C:\1"
Shell("cmd.exe /c " & commandc)
```

А как можно получить ответ из консоли ?
К примеру результат команды **dir C:1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

```
Dim process As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
With process.StartInfo
    .FileName = "..."
    .Arguments = "..."
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .RedirectStandardError = True
    .RedirectStandardInput = True
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    .CreateNoWindow = False
End With

Dim reader As StreamReader = process.StandardOutput
process.WaitForExit()

dim output as string 
output = reader.ReadToEnd()
```